# No aparecen todos los LinearLayout definidos en la pantalla

Tags: android-studio

Tengo este código XML, el cual no logro que muestre los 3 LinearLayout (CABEZA, CUERPO, PIE), los cuales deben cubrir el 100% de la pantalla, solo muestra los dos primeros LinearLayout (CABEZA, CUERPO).

Necesito que quede como muestra la figura-1 y que cuando le aplique invisibilidad = GONE a PIE, quede como muestra la figura-2.

Necesito que quede como muestra la figura-1 y que cuando le aplique invisibilidad = GONE a PIE, quede como muestra la figura-2.

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/cabeza"
   android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="CABEZA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cuerpo"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="CUERPO"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pie"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="PIE"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Para qué metes un linearlayout dentro de otro? No tiene mucho sentido que hagas un LinearLayout para CADA elemento.

Comment: Benito-B, en en el ejemplo solo coloque un elemento en cada LINEARLAYOUT para que no fuera tan largo el código de la explicacion, la verdad en cada LINEARLAYOUT hay varios elementos, que aparecen o desaparecen en grupo de la pantalla cuando modifico la propiedad INVISIBILIDAD a cualquiera de los 3 LINEARLAYOUT. Es un juego basico con los elementos de cada parte del cuerpo,lo que estoy intentando hacer para mis alumnos, no soy programadora soy profesora de primaria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el LinearLayout central , tiene definida como altura `android:layout_height="match_parent"` lo cual no es correcto en este caso, cambia a `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cuerpo"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Te sugiero usar también el atributo:

**[android:layout_weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_weight)**

para definir porcentajes por ejemplo, definiendo "0.30", "1" y "0.40" respectivamente a cada layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cabeza"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CABEZA" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cuerpo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CUERPO" />

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pie"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.40"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PIE" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

obtendrías algo similar a lo que deseas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Elenasys no sabia que existía la propiedad layout_weight, la aplique y me funciona tal cual necesitaba, muchas gracias. Tengo otra duda realcionada, la debo hacer en una pregunta nueva o la puedo hacer en esta? Gracias

Comment: si es algo diferente o relacionado puedes realizar otra pregunta sin problema.